# How to create a custom widget that shows on notification panel using flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image: I want to create a widget like this]
**Suggest me any course, package or answer me directly. Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

**Check out this example and adjust it based on your requirements**
https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/273/add-action-button-on-local-notification-flutter/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).